# My Django URLs not picking up dashes

Tags: django, django-urls

Im trying to work out a url that will match domain.com\about-us\ & domain.com\home\

I have a url regex:

```
^(?P<page>\w+)/$
```

but it won't match the url with the - in it.

I've tried

```
^(?P<page>\.)/$
^(?P<page>\*)/$
```

but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Try:
`^(?P<page>[-\w]+)/$`

[-\w] will accept a-z 1-9 and dash

Comment: Regular expressions are definitely not my strong suit, so this helped me out a ton!