# Django URL Variables - Business Name in URL in stead of ID

Tags: python, django, url, seo

Trying to pass Business Name in URL in stead of ID. When I pass IDs, everything is fine.

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^(?P<name>\w+)/$', 'views.business'),
```

**views.py**

```
def business(request, name=1):
    return render_to_response('business.html', 
                             {'business': business.objects.get(name=name) })
```

**template.html**

```
<a href="http://website.com/{{ business.name|slugify }}/">Name{{ business.name }}</a>
```

When I do this, it will only work for single word business name such as "Bank" however if the business has multiple words "Wells Fargo" it will not work.

My goal is to use slugify to pass short SEO friendly URL such as

```
http://website.com/business-name/
```

Thanks for your time and for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by "will not work"? What are you getting in case of `Wells Fargo`?

Comment: Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/Wells%20Fargo/

Comment: Same for the when using slugify link with hyphen Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/Wells-Fargo/

Comment: Thank you for describing the problem in more detail - it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to allow dashes in your url configuration:

```
url(r'^(?P<name>[-\w]+)/$', 'views.business'),
```

`[-\w]+` matches "alphanumeric" characters in any case, underscore (_) and a dash.

Also, in the view, you need to "unslugify" the value passed in:

```
def business(request, name='unknown'):
    name = name.replace('-', ' ').capitalize()
    return render_to_response('business.html', 
                             {'business': business.objects.get(name=name) })
```

Also see:

- [My Django URLs not picking up dashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531243/my-django-urls-not-picking-up-dashes)
- [docs on slugify](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slugify)
- [How do I create a slug in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837828/how-do-i-create-a-slug-in-django)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Query error: I guess the query cant match the name with the hyphen in it. DoesNotExist at /wells-fargo/
Business matching query does not exist.
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/wells-fargo/
Django Version: 1.5.4
Exception Type: DoesNotExist
Exception Value: 
Business matching query does not exist.

Comment: Perhaps the view should have some kind of replace('-', ' ') function to remove the hyphens from the URL to match the name in DB?

Answer (score 1):

Accordint to [re module docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) **\w**:

> matches any alphanumeric character and the underscore

and the url you are trying to match has a dash because django's slugify method converts spaces and some non-ascii chars into dashes. So the fix consists in modifying the urls.py pattern to:

```
url(r'^(?P<name>[\w-]+)/$', 'views.business'),
```

But this isn't enough. Your current view will try to get a Business instance with the slugified name and will throw a DoesNotExists exception. So you should do one of the folowing things:

- Add an slug field to your Business model which value must be `slugify(business.name)`
- or add an id to the url, like this:

  url(r'^(?P[\w-]+)/(?P\d+)/$', 'views.business'),

and modify your view to get the instance by id:

```
def business(request, name, obj_id):
    return render_to_response('business.html', {'business': business.objects.get(id=obj_id) })
```

Comment: Same as above. Query error: I guess the query cant match the name with the hyphen in it. DoesNotExist at /wells-fargo/
Business matching query does not exist.
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/wells-fargo/
Django Version: 1.5.4
Exception Type: DoesNotExist
Exception Value: 
Business matching query does not exist. Thanks for the help either way!

Comment: right, I edited my answer to fix that. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Some great ideas and even though temporarily I went with the above, I'm planning to add the slugify(business-name) to the Models so we can better control the URL values. Thanks again!